# How to fire a function from within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a function that's created from one program and then in the UI of another program, I have.  That first program builds the code and the second one renders it.

Here's the question.

The JSON object contains a FUNCTION as a string because that's how it's coming from the NODE SERVICE into the Angular 5.x UI

Here's the JSON

```
{
  "test": {
  "trigger": "load",
  "functionName": [
           "function(){if(1 === 1){console.log('hello');} else {console.log('goodbye');}" **<== CORRECTED the original single = that Johnathan caught.**
    ]
  }
}
```

That's the simplest way I can show it.  Yes, there are "" around the {} which is INVALID JSON but the state machine we're using on the backend renders (sanitizes)  it that way and on the client.

Bottom line: what I'm trying to achieve is the ability to call standard JavaScript functions like, onBLur, onChange, onHover, onMouseOver, etc...some functions are irrelevant...but we definitely need, onBlur and onChange.

I did this back in Angular 1.6 with app.js and the router whereby I called functions inside a JSON object that called the function on the controller.  Wala! It was easy with **$scope.$parent.functionName(arg1 if any){}**

I simply wrote:

```
....,
onEntry: (function() {
     do something cool here...
}),
....
```

So, with TypeScript, how can I achieve the same thing?

I hope I'm clear with my question?

Thanks

UPDATE!!!!

Here's a screen shot of the DEV console capturing the ACTUAL code, sorry, last night was from memory.

[image: Dev Console showing JSON with function]

Hope this helps with clarification of my question.

Comment: JSON is strict key-object pair. All the keys are string and all values can be string, number, Boolean, array only. Even assigning function to a key is not allowed in JSON object. This is not to be misunderstood when we do use JSON object in module.exports with multiple functions as value.

Comment: Not TRUE! See my update. We are exporting functions... and JSON is actually doing it.  I've done it with Angular 1.6 in the app.js inside the Route, where I call a function, inside JSON and call said function from the old controller... Remember?

Comment: can we send a function in API request using application/json? like `{main:function() {}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, but be sure your are doing your condition with `===` instead `=`, and putting all your brackets.

```js
let myTest = {
    "test": {
        "trigger": "load",
        "functionName": function(){if(1 === 1){console.log('hello');} else {console.log('goodbye');}}
    }
};

myTest.test.functionName();
```

Comment: Johnathan,  you have a foreign double quote at the end or do we need one before "function...?

Comment: Correct, sorry, I was rushing with the equals sign

Comment: the answer is correct, except the object in the answer is no longer at all related to JSON

Comment: Correct... but the bottom section, I don't need.  This has got to fire onBlur of a field... this is the output that's showing in the Dev Console.  I have to somehow, make the onBlur function FIRE what that action occurs.  there is no let myTest... there's just the { that encloses the entire thing and the closing }.  Imagine a json object and this is inside it.  That functionName is what is going to fire.  but, it doesn't.  There are no errors... when I get to work, I'll send more details.